# Jasper Report with List or Collection of Pojos

Tags: jasper-reports

This question is about Jasper Reports.

Suppose I want to create a Jasper Report using `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` like this ...

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(JRLoader.getInputStream(fileName), parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(aList));
```

And suppose that the PoJo I am using has a Property of type List.

How can I access

1. The individual items in this List,
2. and if this item is itself a Pojo access it's properties in Jasper Report XML 
   file.

For example in the Jasper XML file:

```
...field name="?????" class="java.lang.String" ...
```

Thanks for your help ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your data source has fields of type List (more generally, of type java.util.Collection), then you can use a Table or List or Subreport component to iterate through them. Use one of those elements and set its data source like this:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{myListField})
```

You could also add your own helper class with a static method to deal with these fields appropriately.

This comes up a lot with MongoDB. I wrote an article on [Collections in JasperReports](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/collections-in-reports-on-mongodb/). It uses MongoDB as the data source... but it would apply equally well to your POJO data source.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I also found this page about this issue: http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2008/7/12/Using-The-JasperReports-Struts2-Plugin-A-Main-Report-And-A-Subreport